# Return result from python script in Node JS child process

Tags: node.js

Im trying to return the value from a python script from a nodejs child process and i just cant seem to get it to work, it prints in the console using console.log correctly as it should but only returns undefined, i was wondering if there is a way to directly return that value, or to parse the console.log results into a string.

```
var sys = require('util');
module.exports = function() {
    this.getPlay = function getPlaylist(name) {
        const childPython = spawn('python' ,['main.py', name]);
        var result = '';
        childPython.stdout.on(`data` , (data) => {
            result += data.toString();

        });
    
        childPython.on('exit' , () => {
            console.log(result);
        
        });
        
    }};
```

Python script is empty for now and prints "Hello 'name' "
Edit:
I tried to use promises and here is what i have:

```
    (async function(){
        function test(name) {
            return new Promise((resolve , reject) => {
                const childPython = spawn('python' ,['main.py', "He"]);
                var result = '';
                childPython.stdout.on(`data` , (data) => {
                    result += data.toString();
                });
            
                childPython.on('close' , function(code) {
                    t = result
                    resolve(result)
                });
                childPython.on('error' , function(err){
                    reject(err)
                });
        
            })};
        
        var t;
        await test(name);
        console.log(t);
        return t;
        })();
```

Comment: Can you also post your python script. What are you returning from python and how?

Comment: @kg99 for now just printing hello 'name' , trying to understand how this works

Comment: Then your code should work. just test with only print "hello" in your python script. The buffer should collect the output data. just call it like const childPython = spawn('python' ,['main.py']);. I think you are doing something wrong in your script.

Comment: @kg99 it works fine, but it only prints the result in the console, i would like to send that result into a variable to use somewhere else in my code

Comment: Your already stored it in results. Can you add console.log(results).

Comment: @kg99 when i console.log(results) outside the .on method i get undefined, but when i print it inside i get "Hello 'name' "

Comment: Yes, because by that time the data event is not called. have a look at https://nodejs.org/en/docs/guides/blocking-vs-non-blocking/. if you want to use it that way, turn the getPlay function into a promise. resolve it when you get the results.

Comment: @kg99 i cant seem to get it to work properly even when using await and promises, it prints outside of the function but is never saved to a variable proprely

Comment: Can you add you code that uses promises.

Comment: @kg99 i've updated my post. This works but i still would want to call the function elsewhere in my code and it still returns undefined

Comment: Have a look at my answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Define it like this.

```
 function getPlaylist(name) {
      return new Promise((resolve , reject) => {
          const childPython = spawn('python' ,['main.py', name]);
          var result = '';
          childPython.stdout.on(`data` , (data) => {
              result += data.toString();
          });
      
          childPython.on('close' , function(code) {
              resolve(result)
          });
          childPython.on('error' , function(err){
              reject(err)
          });
  
      })
    };
```

Remeber to use try...catch for it it gets rejected. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/try...catch

```
async function runTest() {
  try {
    const playList = await getPlaylist();
    console.log(playList);
  } catch (err) {

  }
}
 
runTest()
```

Comment: So if i want to manipulate the string playList would i just set a variable = to the runTest() and manipulate that?

Comment: yes. you can do anything with the variable.

Answer (score 2):

```
const {spawn} = require('child_process');

const getPythonScriptStdout = (pythonScriptPath) => {
    const python = spawn('python', [pythonScriptPath]);
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        let result = ""
        python.stdout.on('data', (data) => {
            result += data
        });
        python.on('close', () => {
            resolve(result)
        });
        python.on('error', (err) => {
            reject(err)
        });
    })
}


getPythonScriptStdout('./python.py').then((output) => {
    console.log(output)
})
```

python.py file

```
print("hi from python")
```